# Chaining file inclusions

Tags: racket

I have a file, `configuration.rkt`:
(define file-path "path/to/file.rkt")

Then I have the 'main' file `program.rkt`, in which I would like to include the file specified by `file-path`. I tried this way, but it does not work:

```
(include "configuration.rkt")
(include file-path)
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @soegaard said, you want to use Racket's module system via `require`, instead of textually including source files. It will save you a ton of grief.

I noticed that you seem to want the choice of source file to be determined at runtime?

If so, two options:

1. You could use [units and signatures](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/units.html).
2. You could use [`dynamic-require`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Module_Names_and_Loading.html?q=dynamic-require#%28part._dynreq%29). For example:

config.rkt:

```
#lang racket

(provide to-be-required)

(define to-be-required "foo.rkt")
```

foo.rkt:

```
#lang racket

(provide foo-value
         foo-proc)

(define foo-value "I am from foo.rkt and I was dynamic-required!")

(define (foo-proc)
  "I am foo-proc.")
```

main.rkt

```
#lang racket

(require "config.rkt")

(printf "Let's dynamic-require ~a, as config.rkt said.\n" to-be-required)

(define foo-value (dynamic-require to-be-required 'foo-value))
(define foo-proc  (dynamic-require to-be-required 'foo-proc))

foo-value
(foo-proc)
```

Output:

```
Let's dynamic-require foo.rkt, as config.rkt said.
"I am from foo.rkt and I was dynamic-required!"
"I am foo-proc."
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `require` instead of `include`.

http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/module-require.html